# How do i import a custom jsx component into another jsx file?

Tags: react-native, jsx

I am trying my hands on using jsx for my react native projects. I wanted to import a custom component i created from a different module but importing it to the main App.jsx file is giving me errors Module not found at {path} but in searching, ES-LINT gave me the correct folder suggestion to where the custom component was. How do i work around this?

`import {Card } from './Animation/Components/Card'`

The path was underlined and the component couldn't be imported

Comment: Can you please upload a screenshot of your folder structure?

Comment: perhaps `import Card from './Animation/Components/Card'` might work?

Comment: @frozen, i tried this, didnt work

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your folder structure as well as the code for exporting the component in the Card file? @user13707546